# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in Angular 6 , when lazy loaded routes are clicked after some time (without any action in browse)r)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

angular-cli :7.3.1

@angular/core": "^6.1.10",

i have added below routes in app module

```
{ path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", component: AppHomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: "business",
    component: MainNavComponent,
    data: {
      route_data: [
        {
          name: "Monthly",
          route: "business-view"
        },
        {
          name: "Overview",
          route: "overview"
        },
        { name: "Manual Update",
         route: "manual-update" }
      ],
      header: "DFIN"
    },
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "business-view", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "business-view", component: BusinessViewComponent },
      { path: "overview", component: OverallStatusComponent },
      {
        path: "manual-update",
        loadChildren:
          "src/app/manual-updates/manual-updates.module#ManualUpdatesModule"
      }
    ]
```

also in lazy loaded module i have below code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ManualUpdatesComponent , canActivate:[RoleGuard],data: {role: ['SUPPORT','ADMIN']}}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
```

so when click on manual-update route it will work at first , but after some time (when i shift to different tab in browser and come back after 15 min) and when i click again on manual-update will give below error.

```
main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at t.applyUpdate (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.init (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at t.forEach (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at t._subscribe (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at t.subscribe (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at t.call (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at t.subscribe (main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1)
    at main.6fb2ceda7fab4d6bc775.js:1
```

Comment: You might be adding a `null` header to some http request. Check all http requests that are made, i.e. in your Guard or HttpInterceptors.

Comment: @fridoo i didnt set any null headers

Comment: Well, `applyUpdate` points towards HttpHeaders. Properties of headers are also not allowed to be `null`.